# Issue in single instance of an activity in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have two activities. `A` and `B`. `A` starts `B`. Both are running in the screen and both are visible. Say now `B` is visible.

On a special key press, I want to bring the `A` to the front and make it active. The problem I am facing is when the special key is pressed, another instance of `A` is launched and the new instance is brought to the front.

But I want the original `A` to come to the front. I want to make this change in the framework layer rather than application specific by using the `singleInstance` theme in the launchMode in `AndroidManifest` file.

Comment: Sounds like Tabs http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: Oh right this is a ROM question

Answer (score 1):

From Google's Android-documentation:

> Defining launch modes
>
> Launch modes allow you to define how a
>   new instance of an activity is
>   associated with the current task. You
>   can define different launch modes in
>   two ways: Using the manifest file
>
> When you declare an activity in your
>   manifest file, you can specify how the
>   activity should associate with tasks
>   when it starts. Using Intent flags
>
> When you call startActivity(), you can
>   include a flag in the Intent that
>   declares how (or whether) the new
>   activity should associate with the
>   current task.

So you can start your Activity A from Activity B using an **Intent** and passing the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** flag.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use the manfiest to achieve that?

If changes in the manifest were possible from the code the application would be able to change it's permissions after installation which doesn't make sense.

Comment: The change which i want to make should be visible for all applications and not only for a particular application.So I need to change the framework , so that wenever the special key is pressed, the activity at the back should come to the front with out launchng a new instance.

Comment: @Revathi K J: oh, so you are doing a custom rom. Try to see where android parses the xml and hardcode there the `singleInstance` flag.